# vs 2008 -> 2010 : The project type is not supported by this installation (sharepoint)

Tags: sharepoint, upgrade

When I open a visual studio 2008 vsewss 1.3 sharepoint project in visual studio 2010 and run the conversion wizard I get the error "The project type is not supported by this installation".

I have installed the visual studio 2010 SDK, vsewss 1.3, and tried on 3 different machines using different accounts. I've installed vs 2010 service pack 1 where an internet connection is available and run repair/reinstall more than once to ensure vs 2010 installed correctly. Short of sacrificing a goat to the great satan / sharepoint's birth mother I'm out of ideas

The ProjectTypeGuids are sharepoint C# and windows C#:
{593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}

Any suggestions as to what else "*The project type is not supported by this installation*" might mean are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Visual Studio 2008 extensions for SharePoint to get the SharePoint project type:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/DE3F57B5-9337-4D5E-A055-11FE697048D1